# devenv copies files from other project during incremental build

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, incremental-build

I have 3 projects; `Project1.Web`, `Project1.Service` and `Project1.Common`.
Both `Project1.Web` and `Project1.Service` have dependencies on `Project1.Common`.

- If I **rebuild** the solution which contains all 3 projects; all works correctly.
- If I change a file in `Project1.Web`; files are built to Project1.Web\bin - all works correctly.
- If if change a file in `Project1.Service` files are built to Project1.Service\bin\Debug **AND some are copied to Project1.Web\bin**. The copied file is Project1.Common.dll, but Project1.Web.dll is not built (or copied).
- The file modified in `Project1.Service` is not shared, its just modified to trigger an incremental build of `Project1.Service`.

Does anyone know why Visual Studio would be copying a build artifact to a a directory that is not part of the incremental build?

Currently this sequence of events leaves `Project1.Web` is a non-working state as `Project1.Service` and `Project1.Web` have dependencies on different versions of the same assembly via a third party assembly. If we decide to make a change to `Project1.Service` then it has the side-effect of breaking `Project1.Web`.

I've tried/checked the following:

1. There are no dependencies between `Project1.Web` and `Project1.Service` (either direction).
2. The file modified in `Project1.Service` is not shared; and there are no pre/post build events defined.
3. Executing msbuild on the Project1.Service.csproj project file does not have the same effect.
4. Denying write/create permission on the bin directory under `Project1.Web` does not cause the incremental build to fail.
5. No output is emitted in the detailed or diagnostic msbuild output that references `Project1.Web` (from within Visual Studio)
6. Using `procmon`, I can see that devenv is using `mswebprj.dll` (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\mswebprj.dll) - which invokes the copy of the file.

Comment: Experiencing same problem in vs2015